# How to get value from database on list item click according to position of list item

Tags: android

I can add to a db and list as a listview. When I click a list item using onListItemClick, what statement do I need to get the value?

```
 package cabs.h;

import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
    public class planner extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Long mRowId;
    private ServerResponce AllList;
    // private DeviceListAdapter AllList;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listonruntime);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        String responce = null ;
       // startManagingCursor(responce);
        //AllList = new ServerResponce(responce);
    }
    private void fillData() {
        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NUMBER};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.toptext,R.id.middletext,R.id.circle};

       SimpleCursorAdapter notes =   
                                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, notesCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(notes);

    }




    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

      @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
       // ServerResponce servresp=new ServerResponce();
       String responceId = Activity1.getData();
        String responceno = Activity2.getData();
        String city = cabbookingapplication.Selection;
        String area = cabbookingapplication.Selection2;
        String exactadd  = cabbookingapplication.Selection3;
        String nearby = cabbookingapplication.Selection4;
        private void saveState() {
        String title =("FROM LOC::"+city+","+area+","+exactadd+","+nearby);
        String body = ("TO LOC::"+city+","+area+","+exactadd+","+nearby);
        String number = (""+responceno+",,"+responceId);
            if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, number);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body,number);
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);
        String resposponseid = Activity2.getData();
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);


       // String device_name = (String) (planner.this). getListAdapter().getItem(position);


        Toast.makeText(this, "this row responceid is= " + " " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();

    }

}
```

and on list item click i want retrive value of saved in list item according to row position
what to do

```
 @Override
    **protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);
        String resposponseid = Activity2.getData();
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItemId(position);



          Toast.makeText(this, "this row responceid is= " + " " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }**
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documentation for the method [onListItemClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) you can see that the last parameter is the row id of the clicked item.

> This method will be called when an
>   item in the list is selected.
>   Subclasses should override. Subclasses
>   can call
>   getListView().getItemAtPosition(position)
>   if they need to access the data
>   associated with the selected item.
>
> Parameters
>
> l:    The ListView where the click happened
>
> v:    The view that was clicked within the ListView
>
> position:      The position of the view in the list
>
> id:   The row id of the item that was
>   clicked

But to get a proper row id it is important that the cursor which was passed to the adapter contains a row called '**_id**' representing unique id for each row in the table.